# How to fill a range with values that are dependent on the previous value?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, named-ranges

'I'm attempting to fill a named range with revenue. The first cell of the named range already has a value and represents the current year (year 0) of revenue. I want to use a random stochastic process to forecast year 1's revenue by using year 0's revenue. And then forecast year 2's revenue by using year 1's revenue. My problem is that all the cells of the range are receiving the beginning revenue value of year 0.

```
Sub RevenuePathSimulation()

Range("starttime") = Time
Dim RR As Variant
RR = Array()

Dim N As Double
N = Range("runs").Value
Dim years As Double
years = Range("RevRng").Count
Dim mean As Long
mean = Range("mean")
Dim sigma As Long
sigma = Range("sigma")
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For j = 2 To years
    RR(1, j) = RR(1, j - 1) * Exp(mean + sigma * Rnd())
    Range("RevRng").Value = RR(1, j)
    Debug.Print RR(1, j)
Next j
Range("stoptime") = Time

End Sub

    ' The end result is to have revenues for years 0 to 10
    ' derived from a random stochastic process.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question or problem?

Comment: Well, currently the code is not filling the named range "RevRng" with values. The named range "RevRng" consists of 12 empty cells. The first cell already has a value. I need to fill the rest of the cells with values from left to right by using the previous value and a random stochastic process. At present this isn't working

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
RR(1, j) = RR(1, j - 1) * Exp(mean + sigma * Rnd())
```

updates the array (`RR` is an array, not a range).

If you want to see the cells on the worksheet updated, write the array back to the sheet after the loop and before the subroutine ends:

```
Range("RevRng").Value = RR
```

Otherwise, I think what you've done is taken some data from the sheet, done some calculations, then let the results go out of scope (when the subroutine ends) without updating the sheet with the computed results.

Overall, the code might look something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RevenuePathSimulation()

    Dim RR As Variant
    Dim N As Double
    Dim years As Double
    Dim mean As Long
    Dim sigma As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Range("starttime") = Time
    Range("RevRng") = Array()
    RR = Range("RevRng")
    N = Range("runs").Value
    years = Range("RevRng").Count
    mean = Range("mean")
    sigma = Range("sigma")

    For i = 1 To N
        For j = 2 To years
            RR(1, j) = RR(1, j - 1) * Exp(mean + sigma * Rnd())
            Debug.Print RR(1, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    Range("RevRng").Value = RR ' <-- This is the only thing you're missing.

    Range("stoptime") = Time

    ' The end result is to have revenues for years 0 to 10
    ' derived from a random stochastic process.

End Sub
```

The values I've used for `sigma`, `mean` and `runs` and the revenues yielded are likely nonsensical (to you), but as you can see, the revenue figures appear to be different. My `RevRng` consists of the yellow cells.

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks very much chillin that has made a slight improvement but now all the cells in "RevRng" have the value of the first cell. How do I get the cells to take the new value?

Comment: @user3693832, if I create the required named ranges and run your code exactly as it is, I get different values in my `RevRng` range. To me this suggests, the issue lies either in the values you have for `sigma`, `mean`, `runs`, or maybe `RevRng` range is not horizontal. You can step through the code with `F8` key. You can view the state of variables in the Locals Window (`View > Locals Windows`). I'll attach a screenshot of my worksheet, so you can see what I see (in case it helps).

Comment: 'Based on your advice this is what my code looks like now

Comment: @user3693832, see edit. I mentioned that it should go after the loop -- and that you should write the entire array `RR`, not a specific array element `RR(1, j)`, to the range. Hope that clears things up. If not, let me know.

Comment: hey @chillin I've copied and pasted your entire amended code but still all the values are the same as the first cell in the range. Any other suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: @user3693832, do you see different values being printed (by `Debug.Print`) in the immediate window? What values are `mean`, `runs`, `sigma` on your sheet? And what is the value of the first cell in `RevRng`? I will try to run the code with those same values.

Comment: I've deleted 'runs' as a variable and deleted the first For Loop because it seemed redundant. The 'mean' is 0.06, 'years' is 12, and 'sigma' is 0.12. The starting revenue value is 1,916,475

Comment: apologies for deleting 'runs' after you've helped but don't actually need it

Comment: also all the values in the immediate window are the same as first value in RevRng which 1,9116,475

Comment: it's sorted. Thank you very much for your help you're an absolute beast of a legend.

Comment: @user3693832, seem like `Exp(mean + sigma * Rnd())` evaluates to `1` during each loop iteration, so calculation becomes `19116475 * 1`.

Comment: Okay, you've got it, great.